# How to turn a defined function function into an anonymous one

Tags: clojure

I want to turn a defined function into an anonymous one. How do I do that? The following function returns the last element from a sequence:

```
(defn lastt [l]
    (cond
        (nil? (next l)) l
        :else
            (lastt (next l))))
```

How do I turn it into `fn` form?

PS: I know about `last` function, this is just an exercise.

Comment: Do you still want to define a function, or do you just want an anonymous function?

Comment: Please update the question with the requested information. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, that function returns a list with the last item in it. I'd change your definition so that it returns **just** the last item:

```
(defn lastt [l]
  (cond
   (nil? (next l)) (first l)
   :else (lastt (next l))))
```

To simplify, I'd use a `let` binding since you're calling `next` twice on `l`:

```
(defn lastt [l]
  (let [n (next l)]
    (cond
     (nil? n) (first l)
     :else (lastt n))))
```

The next thing I'd do is replace the final call to `lastt` to use `recur` instead

```
(defn lastt [l]
  (let [n (next l)]
    (cond
     (nil? n) (first l)
     :else (recur n))))
```

And then I'd replace that with

```
#(let [n (next %)]
   (cond
    (nil? n) (first %)
    :else (recur n)))
```

And just realised that it could be simplified even more using destructuring :)

```
#(let [[h & t] %]
   (cond
    (nil? t) h
    :else (recur t)))
```

**Updated**

No need for the `cond`, since there's only two branches, and using `fn` instead of the `#` shorthand will allow the destructuring to happen in the `fn`'s parameters, making the whole function a little bit more concise:

```
(fn [[h & t]]
  (if (empty? t) h
      (recur t)))
```

Comment: Thanks, almost feel like I know what I'm doing half the time now. :)

Comment: You can use `if` instead of `cond` here, and using `fn` instead of `#` will let you do the destructuring directly in the args: `(fn [[h & t]] (if (empty? t) h (recur t)))`

Comment: Ah, didn't think about the if, but had thought about the fn. Was just too lazy to update the answer. :) I think the fn is nicer, since it is a little bit more concise.

Answer (score 6):

I'm more of a schemer/CLer than a clojer, but `(defn f [args] body)` looks to be mostly syntactic sugar for `(def f (fn f ([args] body)))`, in which case `lastt` could be written as an anonymous function by leaving out the [`def`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28def%20symbol%20init?%29):

```
(fn lastt 
    ([l] (cond
           (nil? (next l))
             l
           :else
             (lastt (next l)))))
```

Since `lastt` recurses, you need to provide a name to bind it to within the body.